# C++ vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, vector

I keep getting this error when I try to run my program after compiling it:

```
vector subscript out of range
```

my code is like :

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    getline(input, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> num;
    while (!iss.eof()) {
        iss >> o;
        b.push_back(o);
    }
    sort(b.begin(), b.end);
    se = b.size();
    output << num << " " << b[se-1] << endl;
    b.clear();
    b.resize(100);
}
```

And the file looks like:

```
3
1 5 6 1 3 50 600
2 4 5 7 8 3 6
4 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So , where is the problem?

Comment: one of the problems is that we dont know about most of the types involved in your code excerpt, or whatever has been done with these, or where that error is actually issued.

Comment: You need `b.end()` instead of `b.end`.

Comment: While I don't know if it is related to your problem, the loop `while ( !iss.eof() )` is clearly incorrect, and will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler complain about the types of the arguments in the call to sort?

Comment: First bit of advice: make sure all warnings are on, and consider ***any*** warning as an ***error***. In the line `sort (b.begin(),b.end);`, your omission of braces after `b.end` must have caused a compiler warning (I'm actually a bit surprised it managed to compile at all). Ignoring this warning is one of the reasons why you are here and we are struggling to debug your code.

Comment: `b[b.size()-1]` can be simplified to `b.back()`. Outputting the contents of an iterator range can be achieved using `copy(b.begin(), b.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort (b.begin(),b.end);`

You're using the address of b's end function to `sort`, not the iterator that `b.end()` would return had you called it, so the sort algorithm will stumble off the end of your vector, which causes the 'subscript out of range' error you're reporting.  (If you had iterator debugging disabled, it'd do far worse than reporting that error!)

This should be

`sort (b.begin(),b.end());`

**edit**

You might also want to check that your vector isn't empty, as that's another place you could be referencing outside of its bounds:

```
se = b.size();
if( se > 0 )
    output << num << " " << b[se-1] << endl;
```

Comment: it's the same.. i tried b.end() .. and i keep get vector subscript out of range

Comment: `sort( b.begin(), b.end )` shouldn't compile.  He says he gets a bounds error when he runs the program (so he obviously didn't post the actual code).

Comment: @user2973413 That solved _one_ of the problems.  Your `while` loop still has undefined behavior, although it may work most of the time.  (It will go into an endless loop if the file contains some illegal input, and it will push back a possibly uninitialized value if there is white space between the last value and the end of line.)

Answer (score 1):

You store the first number in a line in the `num` variable, and only subsequent numbers in the vector. So the first time you call `output<<num<<" "<<b[se-1]<<endl;` the vector `b` is empty, and the expression `se-1` is -1, which is out of range.

Comment: It is the first line of the input file that triggers the problem, to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted the actual code (since the code you posted
won't compile), and you've not given us any hint about the types
involved.  But if `num` and `o` are numeric types, and `b` is
a `vector` of numeric types, and there is no additional white
space between the `3` and the end of line in the first line, the
first time through the loop, you'll probably (almost certainly)
not enter the `while`, `b` will be empty (`b.size() == 0`), and
`b[se - 1]` will attempt to access some incredible large index
in an empty array.

Of course, if `num` is `complex`, or some other type for which
`"3"` is not a legal value, you'll enter an endless loop with
`while (!iss.eof())`.  The correct form of the loop would be:

```
while ( iss >> o ) {
    b.push_back( o );
}
```

The fact that you use the value `o` without checking whether you've
actually succeeded in reading it can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you man .. it is the actual code but i was doing sort (b.begin(),b.begin()+b.size()) and i just replaced it with b.end and forgot ()